# Azure AD Connect do not start

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory

I was trying to configure AD Connect to allow Hybrid join. When the app ask for Global Administrator credentials I got an error that I need to Restart Azure AD Connect with the / Interactive Auth.

When I did that using terminal and command AzureADConnect.exe /InteractiveAuth I cannot open AD Connect app anymore.
It shows - This app cannot run on your PC

OS version - MS Server 2022

Comment: try running the application in compatibility mode. Right-click on the application icon, select "Properties", and then choose the "Compatibility" tab. From there, you can select an earlier version of Windows to run the application in compatibility mode.

Comment: I tried that but still I cannot run the app.  Also I don't want to reinstall in because then we should set up AD Connect from beginning.

Answer (score 1):

@Marcis As per the prerequisites mentioned here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-prerequisites#:%7E:text=note%20that%20Windows%20Server%202022%20is%20not%20yet%20supported. Azure AD Connect installation on Windows Server 2022 is not yet supported.

Comment: Yes, thank you for replay. We build the server from backup and now all works.